# Best way to get a correlation matrix from an endpoint

Tags: typescript, firebase, backend, correlation, endpoint

Currently, I save correlations on Google Firebase. The structure looks somewhat like this:

```
{a: {a: 1.0, b: 0.6, c: -0.3, ...}, b: {a: 0.6, b: 1.0, c: -0.5, ...}, ...}
```

I want to retrieve a full correlation matrix efficiently, but I also want to have the freedom to select any combination of items.

I have a working solution by calling, for example
"[GET]: /correlations/a/b", but as you can imagine I have many calls to the endpoint to download a full correlation matrix, even though I already omit via code calling "/correlations/a/b"+"/correlations/b/a" and "/correlations/a/a".

I was reading before creating the post, that I could also use a [POST] request with a body to download the matrix, by only calling the endpoint once. But, is this good practice? Is there a better approach to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make batch requests to return the output. You can use either use parameters in GET requests to get the correlations

```
   /api?q1=cor(a,b)&q2=cor(b,c)
```

or you can use the post requests

```
   /api

where body = {"correlation vars": [(a,b), (c,d)]}
```

1. Try to design API which is more readable.
2. If you wish you pass complex queries then POST request could be a better option.
3. Simpler queries could be created using parameters in GET request
4. Compress data using gZip or byte array so I/O call is faster. Lot of frameworks provides in build support for that.
5. Depending on your requirement measure tradeoffs between CPU computation and cost of I/O calls.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. With `/api?q1=cor(a,b)&q2=cor(b,c)` I would quickly reach the limit of the url, right? I think it was 1000 characters. I think a post request might be the best option. I really like your answer 4. I didn't know so far, that I could do that. Not sure if I can use it on this  problem though. For 5 it's definitely i/o calls. The data is all preprocessed and only updated daily, which fits all of my requirements.